# Problema em passar argumento via linha de comando em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sou iniciante em Python e estou enfreando o seguinte problema para passar um argumento via linha de comando  em Python.

```
from math import pi
import sys


def circulo(r):
    return pi * float(r) ** 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = sys.argv[1]
    area = circulo(r)
    print('Area do circulo ', area)
```

Estou tendo a seguinte saida no terminal:

[image: Saida do Pycharm]

Comment: você tem que colocar no lugar do 1 o valor 0, já que o primeiro índice é 0

Comment: Rodei seu código em minha máquina e não tive problemas. Você está chamando o arquivo ```python``` somente pelo nome? Pois o correto é: ```$ python nome_arquivo.py args```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especificamente neste caso, o interpretador está entendendo que o programa é um *shell script* e não um programa em **Python**. Acrescente o *shabang* -- Seja o `#!/usr/bin/python` ou `#!/usr/bin/env pythom` -- no começo do arquivo para o programa seja corretamente identificado ou chame-o através de `python argumentoLinComand.py`.